# Why are INSERTs and UPDATEs slower on Android 4.0?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

When Android 4.0 became available for Nexus S back in December 2011, we did some performance testing:
http://greendao-orm.com/2011/12/17/sql-performance-in-android-4-0/
[image]

Surprisingly, UPDATE and INSERT performance dropped by half (!) after the Update to Android 4.0 on the same phone. We did not have time to investigate further, but maybe meanwhile somebody else did?

One could speculate, that the file system changed, etc. but I'm looking for hard facts. ;)

Comment: Just to be sure, were you using the stock 2.3? Because some ROMs really improve IO performance by using different file systems together with hacks

Comment: Yes, stock OS. Version 2.3.6 if I recall correctly.

Comment: I'm interested in this too. ICS filesystem is noticeably slower than on older droids, and I can't see any obvious reason for it.

Comment: If you take a look at the sqlite.git from the Android source tree there have been a number of changes between the two versions that are Android specific. I'd start there.

Comment: Are your benchmark scripts accessible? I can't see them at your link. What was the test phone?

Comment: Check the original link (http://greendao-orm.com/2011/12/17/sql-performance-in-android-4-0/), I updated the post with a small how-to.

Comment: Browsing through the git repository I found the following commit (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/a22d88493ea2a0cdd63b026c0d4b524d658a8e65), could this be related? Write ahead logging is supposed to be faster, but I don't know in which versions it might have been enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [blog post by Sony](http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2012/03/30/learn-about-the-technical-differences-between-gingerbread-and-ics/), the difference seems to be caused by the SQLite Android API:

> Another change in ICS compared to Gingerbread is that Google has moved
>   a lot of the SQL handling from the native to the Java layer. In our
>   internal studies, we have seen that read and write operations to the
>   SQL database takes longer time...

I'd like to see a follow up investigation to dive deeper into this issue, e.g. comparing sources. Also, it's odd that Sony claims that read performance is slower, while our measurements showed a ~40% performance improvement.

Comment: I cannot find any proof of this claim when examining the Android source code.